# Elasticsearch - count occurrences of (unpredictable) strings in array

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

Say I have a database which contains the elements such as:

```
{
    "elmName" : "elm1",
    "arrayOfStrings" : [ "str1", "str4", "str2"]
},
{
    "elmName" : "elm2",
    "arrayOfStrings" : ["str4", "str3"]
},
{
    "elmName" : "elm3",
    "arrayOfStrings" : [ "str1"]
},
{
    "elmName" : "elm4",
    "arrayOfStrings" : []
}
```

The strings in the 'arrayOfStrings' are random and unknown at search time.
how can I query the count of all unique elements under 'arrayOfStrings' such as:

```
{
"str4" : 2,
"str2" : 1,
"str1" : 2,
"str3" : 1}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to flatten all the sublists into one, then group by key and count the number of occurrences:

```
 ListOfObjects.SelectMany(x => x.arrayOfStrings).GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(x.Key, x.Count()))
```

[ElasticLinq](https://github.com/ElasticLINQ/ElasticLINQ)